# Map wildcard in .NET Core WebApplication

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How can I create the request mapping so that all requests GET, POST, PUT, ... and all paths execute the same method.

```
var application = WebApplication.Create();
application.Map("/", () =>
{
    return "This is all I do!";
});
application.Run("http://localhost:8080");
```

My guess is that there is a wildcard pattern that will work, but i have tried the following  without success: `"/"`, `"*"`, `"/*"` and `"/**"`.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Wildcard and catch all routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#wildcard-and-catch-all-routes) section of the docs:

```cs
app.Map("/{*rest}", (string rest) => rest);
```

Or you can use "catch all" middleware:

```cs
app.Use(async (HttpContext ctx, Func<Task> _) =>
{
    await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `application.Run` with the RequestDelegate parameter instead of `Map`, to handle any and all requests:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var application = WebApplication.Create();
    
    application.Run(async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("This is all I do!");
    });

    application.Run("http://localhost:8080");
}
```